# From Visio to SQL

Tags: sql, entity, visio, relation

How do we translate something like this into SQL?

[image]

**Entity** A -thick line- **relation** -simple line- **Entity B**

Its easy enough to write any of the other connections, but somehow I can't seem to figure it out when it comes to 1 thick line and a simple one, like shown aboove

I have a primary key which is the date of a football season (Entity A - Season) and an entity (Entity B - Football team) which has 2 primary keys which are it's name and primary key of the Season entity. But 'cause of that doubt I have I can't relate them properly.

Answer (score 0):

Relations do not typically form independent tables (diamonds).  However, for a many-many relationship, you will usually see them in a separate tables.  Depending on your notation [(**there are many**)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model#Diagramming_conventions) your diagram could represent a many-many relationship or a 1:1 relationship.

Strong entities (your rectangles) get tables.

In your ER diagram, you will also typically see attributes for each table in circles connected by lines to the entity itself.  Those attributes are turned into columns for each table.  Attributes which are underlined in the diagram are representative of a primary key for a particular entity.

Additional or strange constraints that aren't typically easily represented in an ER diagram are usually put as side notes.

To answer your question, you must know whether or not it's a many-many relationship; if so, you would create a `SeasonClub` table with the two different primary keys inside it.